# node.js - hapi.js facebook integration (login, registration)

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, passport.js, hapi.js

I'm totally noob in hapi.js

What is the best way to do login and registration via facebook with hapi framework? 
Frontend will send me token, after that I need to connect again to facebook from backend and check user id.

I didn't find tutorial or documentation what explain that implementation with some examples.

I saw lib as passport but only for express.js. Is there any simple way to connect hapijs framework with facebook?

Finally I just did simple request with accessToken by axios to facebook/graph and it's work.

Did you integrate hapi.js with other libraries with complex communication? I tried to use hapijs/bell but it doesn't work for me. 
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In my company, we did the FB login "from scratch". The client send the user info in case it's a signUp call and also a accessToken.

We then check with facebook that the access token is registered with the same email than the one the client send us.

Last verification is that the fbId sent by the client is the same as the one we saved in the database.

It seems to me that it looks like your workflow... It is really possible that we have done something not so secured… I will check Bell in case

Comment: Thaks, what did you do with registration, I mean case when email already exists in your storage, but you don't have fbId, do you connect this two accounts or do you create another?

And what did you use to sent request to FB, did you use some lib, or normal fetch to fb graph?

Comment: For the request, we use a standard request module. If we find an account with the corresponding email but no fbId, we add it to the user. If we have a user with the fbId, we update the email assuming the user has changed his Facebook email. We send an a « call the support error » if we found a user with the corresponding email but a different fbId. This last case is very specific... something like, the user change his email on our service and change to a third email address on Facebook... Concerning Bell, we use hapi 13.x and I didn’t find the corresponding bell version

Answer (score 0):

`@hapi/bell` is your best bet https://hapi.dev/module/bell/providers#facebook

Try with their latest documentation and see if it works now